# How to implement hasNext() method with BufferedReader + StringTokenizer?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have this fast reader class:

```
static class FastReader { 
    BufferedReader br; 
    StringTokenizer st; 

    public FastReader() { 
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    } 

    String next() { 
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements()) { 
            try { 
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()); 
            } 
            catch (IOException  e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
        return st.nextToken(); 
    } 

    int nextInt() { 
        return Integer.parseInt(next()); 
    } 

    long nextLong() { 
        return Long.parseLong(next()); 
    } 

    double nextDouble() { 
        return Double.parseDouble(next()); 
    }

    String nextLine() { 
        String str = ""; 
        try { 
            str = br.readLine(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        return str; 
    } 
    
    int[] readArray(int n) {
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            a[i] = nextInt();
        }
        return a;
    }
    
}
```

I want to stop reading input as soon as I reach end of file. I know this can be done using scanner hasNext() method, How can I implement the same method for my reader class?

PS. I want to read input for this question:
https://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `mark()` then try to read a line, if it is successful you could `reset()` to where you set the mark and return `true` and `false` otherwise.

You would also have to check if the current tokenizer has more tokens left. For example:

```
boolean hasNext() {
    if (st != null && st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        return true;
    }
    String tmp;
    try {
        br.mark(1000);
        tmp = br.readLine();
        if (tmp == null) {
            return false;
        }
        br.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`mark()` takes `readAheadLimit` argument to limit the number of characters that can be read while having that mark set, you could increase that if you're dealing with long lines.

Comment: i am not able to use this function, while(sc.hasNext()) is terminating without taking any input (sc is my FastReader object)

Answer (score 0):

You can cover your code in a **while loop** with the condition that the **user input is not null**.
Example:

```
BuffedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in);
String key = "";
while((key = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   //your code
}
```